# How to Insert N Records in a Single Stored Procedure Call

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, bulkinsert

How would I accomplish being able to insert an unknown number of records into the database using a single stored procedure call?

Say I have this table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE PHONE(
    PhoneID int identity(1,1),
    PhoneNumber varchar(20),
    PersonID int
)
```

And I have the following insert stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Phone_Insert
    @PhoneNumber varchar(20),
    @PersonID int
AS

INSERT 
    PHONE 
VALUES
    (@PhoneNumber, @PersonID)
```

How would I be able to transform this to insert any number of records in a single call to this stored procedure?

Comment: From where are the values going to come?

Comment: You could use a [table-valued parameter](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html) or pass an `xml` parameter containing multiple phone numbers

Comment: Even if you could, with a single call you would be repeating the PhoneNumber and PersonID for every record inserted.

Comment: tornambe, I recognize this, which is why I am asking how to alter the Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some blog posts with code samples that address this topic.

Performance Comparison of Singleton, XML, and TVP Inserts
http://sqlfool.com/2008/11/performance-comparison-of-singleton-xml-and-tvp-inserts/

Bulk Inserts with XML
http://sqlfool.com/2008/11/bulk-inserts-with-xml/

One-to-Many Inserts with Table-Valued Parameters
http://sqlfool.com/2008/11/one-to-many-inserts-with-table-valued-parameters/

HTH.

Comment: Thank you. This is pointing me in the right direction; I now know what I should be researching.